# Should we still use em and % for defining the font-size of the website elements?

Tags: fonts, font-size

I've found many suggestions on using different font-sizes and measure units for websites. Most of them suggest to define body font-size in % (100.1%) and use em for the rest part. I realize this is very useful for preserving the proportions while zooming in and out, especially for older browsers. But today most of the web browsers can constrain the proportions of website elements even for the fixed sized elements.

So should we still use % and em or we can use pixels?

Thank you.

Comment: no, "em" was two months ago, "%" was last month, now we're back to using plain old "px" but experts suggest that within the next couple months "pt" is going to make a major comeback...

Answer (score 2):

I still suggest using em when you are assigning font sizes.  You're right about the newer browsers zooming in, but not everyone upgrades their browser, and accommodating the visually impaired is always a good thing.

Comment: ...and some people would like to be able to use their preferred text size without having to make the images on the page huge (and end up with horizontal scrolling on fixed-width sites).

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 6 ( and 7? ) can't properly zoom for pixels so I would still rely on %/ems.

Comment: ... or "pt" when I don't want to inherit a base font size from a parent element.

Comment: ? **Never** use `pt` on-screen. It's just as unresizable as `px`, but as a bonus is also a different size on different OSs. `pt` is suitable for print stylesheets and nothing else.